# Blocking Certain Areas of Site With PHP

Tags: php, security, session

I dont want users to access other users profiles. So this is what I'm doing. Is it fine?

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_SESSION['username']=='ryan'){
header("location:dash.php");
}
else{
location("location:404.php");
}

?>
```

is this secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *secure* if the user can not modify the value of `$_SESSION['username']` to set it to `ryan`; but you forgot the `exit` after the `header('Location:...')`.

Comment: you must `exit();` after a `header('Location:...');`

Comment: and how do i prevent a user from modifying the value of $_Session?

Comment: he can't do this directly. he can do this only if your code allows him to do so.

Comment: awesome....thanks...best answer...and if you have any link on how to make a session more secure...i'd appreciate it.

Comment: @sarthak You should use at least PHP5.1 because you NEED filter to make your code safe => http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

This is an acceptable solution but only on a very small scale. You should avoid hard coding conditionals based on usernames. If the site has anything over 10 users this will become very cumbersome. And you need to make sure the username can't be easily changed be the user.